# Derivation of Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

sorry for bad title.

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable twice and $f = f''$,    $ f(0) = f'(0)=0$ and I want to prove that $f=0$.

So I started with proving that for $[-1,1]$
because it's differentiable it's continuous in $[-1,1]$, and there is $M\geq |f(x)| $ for any $x$ in $[-1,1]$, suppose $f(x_1)=M$.

We can develop a Taylor polynomial around zero and say that there is a $c$ between zero and $x$ such that:
$$f(x) =f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(c)x^2}{2}= \frac{f(c)x^2}{2}$$
$$ f'(x) = (\frac{f(c)x^2}{2} )' =f(c)x$$

Now my question is:

Is it possible to derive this polynomial and treat $f(c)$ as a constant number?

Because then, since $M$ is maximum then $f'(x_1)=0$ and $f(c)x_1=0$ either way $M=0$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you're using a taylor series, and in your case, a maclurian series, then it should be centered around the same value, in this case, $c=0$. So in the first line you should have that $\frac{f(c)x^2}{2} = \frac{f(0)x^2}{2}=0$. The conclusion that $f=0$ immediately follows given that $f$ is only twice differentiable.

Comment: @CoyCatrett Actually $f$ is infinitely differentiable given the equation.

Comment: @EDX , it says in the question :  "f:R→R [differentiable] twice"

Comment: @Coy Yes but it doesn't say it is **only** twice differentiable. Actually a function verifying $f=f''$ is infinitely differentiable since $f''$ is twice differentiable and if it was precised **only** twice differentiable it wouldn't have any solution because it is infinitely differentiable for that given differentiable equation.

Answer (score 1):

Things can be saw in three ways :

---

**1-Uniqueness of solution with given initial conditions**

Knowing that for a linear homogenous differential equation there exists an unique solution given initial conditions for $f$ and $f'$.

Because $0$ is solution you're function must be 0.

**2-Direct Solving**

Your solution is of the form :

$$\exists(A,B), \forall x,  f(x)=A\cosh(x)+B\sinh(x)$$

So giving your conditions

$$f=0$$

Comment: In fact, the number $c$ is function of $x$ in your 3-th method...

Comment: Yes i mod it ! thanks